# What are good alternative to spreadsheets for making complex corp price list-calculators

Tags: software-development, microsoft-excel

I work in a company which exclusively uses Excel for making price list calculators for selling managers. These price lists are very huge and complicated because of complexity of production, where you need to combine a lot of things like types of details, measurements and so on, and because of that those price lists are very hard and to edit and it takes a lot of time just to add some little things like new color in palet of wood, because you should check a lot of dependencies.

In my opinion using spreadsheets is reckless because: it takes a lot time to do changes; very high chances of making mistakes that will lead to money loss; impossimble to test it for mistakes, the only you can fix are that which found by your managers who use it; it's just laggy and so on.

Company doesn't want to make own soft because it requires to hire programmers and spend a lot of money. So I'm looking for any alternatives that can replace excel in making such type of calculators what will not require huge programming skills. What it may be?

Comment: See "It Is Difficult to Get a Man to Understand Something When His Salary Depends Upon His Not Understanding It" on  [quoteinvestigator.com](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/11/30/salary/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use and sell 'microsoft PowerApps'. You can make a bunch of different applications with similar code to excel. It will require some knowledge but there are free courses for that as well. If all else fails, paying someone to create a PowerApps should be a whole lot cheaper than paying a programmer to do something from scratch

Source: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/
Free education: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/powerplatform/power-apps